# Gson - In generics how to use type T in fromJson?

Tags: java, generics, gson, deserialization

I am trying to use Generics and via Gson, trying to deserialize to type T. Following is my code.

```
public class Test<T> {
    
    private final Subscriber<T> subscriber;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    public interface Subscriber<T> {
        public void onMessage(T message);
    }
    
    public Test(Subscriber<T> subscriber) {     
        this.subscriber = subscriber;       
    }
    
    public void onResponse(CharSequence data) {
        T responseObj = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), <how to get type of T here>);
        subscriber.onMessage(responseObj);
    }
    
}
```

As mentioned in the above code in method `onResponse`, how can I deserialize to object of type T? I know we can pass the type in the constructor and maybe use it. But is there any other cleaner way? If not, I would prefer to leave it to the subscriber and do not use generics here.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I don't know Gson but I assume that second parameter is of type `Class<T>`. Assuming you only expect one concrete class for `T` you could pass that to the constructor as well and store it: `Test(Subscriber<T> subscriber, Class<T> type)`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this wouldn't be possible due to [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). At runtime Java erases the concept of generic types so you can't get a reference to `T.class`.

What you could do is pass a `Class<T>` into the constructor of `Test<T>`. Although it's not the cleanest, it will still be safe.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you can't do `T.class` because of type erasure in runtime and the Java compiler does not have where to take the actual type from. However, the `fromJson` method also accepts `Type` as its second parameter, and `Type` can have various enhancements and implementations. Passing `Type` instances directly is not that safe, because it is not parameterized and loses type control. Passing `Class<T>` is a sort of mitigation: it can preserve the type info to some extent, but it loses type parameterization (e.g., `Class<List<String>>` and `Class<List<Map<String, Integer>>>` will be simply *raw class type* `List.class` -- how to tell Gson which generics to use?). I would do the following:

```java
public final class Test<T> {

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber;
    private final Type type;

    public interface Subscriber<T> {

        void onMessage(T message);

    }

    private Test(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber, final Type type) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Test(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber, final TypeToken<? extends T> typeToken) {
        this(subscriber, typeToken.getType());
    }

    public void onResponse(final CharSequence data) {
        final T responseObj = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), type);
        subscriber.onMessage(responseObj);
    }

}
```

In the example above there are two constructors:

- private one for using *some type* to deserialize from (private because `Type` is something Gson needs, we don't expose our internals);
- public one to get the type from type token (and public because we can guarantee to get the correct `Type` from type token (assuming it's not broken, sure)).